# Xpath: How extracts definite element in braces from attribute?

Tags: json, web-scraping, xpath

How extracts  definite element (for example "author_name" and "likes" ) in braces (html-page) from data-article-info ?

```
    <html>
    ...
    <body>
    ...
          <div class="l-hidden entry_data"
                 data-article-info='{
                    "author_name": "Maria R",
                    "author_type": "self",
                    "tags": [],
                    "comments": 15,
                    "likes": 27,
                    "favorites": 8,
                    "is_advertisement": false,
                    "subsite_label": "marketing",
                    "id": 712141,
                    "is_wide": true,
                    "is_ugc": true,
                    "date": "Wed, 31 May 2023 13:54:50 +0300",
                    "is_special": false            }'>
            </div>
    
    
    </body>
</html>
```

query "//div/@data-article-info"  extract all in braces.

Comment: What tooling do you use for scraping?
The obvious answer: convert the content of @data-article-info to json

Comment: @Siebe-Jongebloed , Screaming Frog

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 3.1 you can do

```
//div/@data-article-info => parse-json()?author_name
```

However, if you're using an off-the-shelf web-scraping tool, then the chances are it only supports XPath 1.0.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately , Screaming Frog support only Xpath 1.0 (https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/web-scraping/#xpath-examples). I have scraped with Screaming Frog and extract in Excel (https://theexcelclub.com/how-to-parse-custom-json-data-using-excel/)